# Error when logging to Jupyterhub with Google Oauth

Tags: google-oauth, jupyterhub

So i am trying to deploy Jupyterhub to teach students about EEG processing. I have succesfully deployed a jupyterhub installation using this guide; https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/add-google-oauth-and-system-service-to-jupyterhub.html on https://lab.golembio.com but i am stuck at google oauth stage.

I have followed the instructions step by step, and added this code to my jupyterhub_config.py:

```
from oauthenticator.google import LocalGoogleOAuthenticator

c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = LocalGoogleOAuthenticator

c.LocalGoogleOAuthenticator.create_system_users = True

c.LocalGoogleOAuthenticator.hosted_domain = ['https://lab.golembio.com', 'https://golembio.com']
c.LocalGoogleOAuthenticator.login_service = 'Google Login'
c.LocalGoogleOAuthenticator.oauth_callback_url = 'https://lab.golembio.com/hub/oauth_callback'
c.LocalGoogleOAuthenticator.oauth_client_id = 'xxxx'
c.LocalGoogleOAuthenticator.oauth_client_secret = 'xxxxx'
#c.JupyterHub.cookie_secret_file = '/srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_cookie_secret'
c.Authenticator.add_user_cmd = ['adduser', '-q', '--gecos', '""', '--disabled-password', '--force-badname']
```

ps: I copy and paste correct oauth client id and oauth client secret to the code...

Now when i open lab.golembio.com there is an option to log in with google but after i click it it returns an error:

Error 400: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: client_id

I could not figure out what is the problem?

Comment: please paste the entire stacktrace

Comment: And the error you posted is saying you are missing `client_id`

Comment: 1-What is a stacktrace?

Comment: yes it says so, but i have added client_id in the real code (i just typed xxx to the post due to security reasons)

Comment: You have `oauth_client_id` but not `client_id`

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks a lot. But where is the client_id??

Comment: In your tutorial link it says.

Comment: Yes! you where right! i change oauth id to client id and it works now. But now there is an internal service error!